# Socket IO server is not reachable when launching from eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, socket.io, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to develop a eclipse plugin. My Socket IO server is implemented in java as follows :

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(3700);
final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
    public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
        System.out.println("onConnected");
    }
});
```

When I run this regularly this works fine, same code if I run it as eclipse application clients are not able to connect to server.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `SocketIOServer` and `ConnectListener` it's going to be impossible for anybody to help you.

Comment: I am following the below link: https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio . Please check the demo link inside it. Same code i copoied